# What is causing the errors in my Prize class?

Tags: java, abstract

My code:

```
public class Prize {
    public static int prizeCount = 0;
    private String itemName;
    private String recipient;

    public Prize(String item, String name) {
        itemName = item;
        recipient = name;
        prizeCount++;
    }

    public static int getPrizeCount() {
        return prizeCount;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(“Contestant “ + recipient + “has won a “ + itemName);
        System.out.println(“A total of “ + prizeCount + “prizes have been given away!!!”);
    }
}

public class PersonTest {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Prize p1 = new Prize(“Movie Tickets”, “Bob”);
        System.out.println(“Prizes so far: “ + p1.getPrizeCount());
        Prize p2 = new Prize(“A NEW CAR!!!”, “Jane”);
        Prize.print();
    }
}
```

What is causing the problem with my code? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Your quotes are wrong, use `" "`

Comment: Use [edit] option to clarify your question with details of problem you are facing like error message, exception stacktrace, expected data vs actual data conflict. You can also temporarily delete it and undelete it when edit is done.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: What is wrong is that **you** have to tell us the error you get. We dont know what your problem is! But yes, most likely, you are using wrong quote " characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use (" ") not the ones in your code.

```
public void print() {
    System.out.println(“Contestant “ + recipient + “has won a “ + itemName);
    System.out.println(“A total of “ + prizeCount + “prizes have been given away!!!”);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides wrong doublequotes, you can't call an instance method with classname.

This won't work.

```
Prize.print();
```

You need to call print method on instance of Prize class. Like this,

```
priceObject.print();
```

Or make the method static then you can call with classname.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either make the `print()` method static or call it on the two instantiated objects. i.e. `p1.print() or p2.print()`